# Adding token generator to Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firebase, token

I'm trying to integrate firechat into a Rails app, and am not sure where to put the snippet that generates tokens for users-- would this go in a messaging model, or similar?? 
The code is below:

```
require "firebase_token_generator"

payload = {:uid => "1", :auth_data => "foo", :other_auth_data => "bar"}

generator = Firebase::FirebaseTokenGenerator.new("   <YOUR_FIREBASE_SECRET>")
token = generator.create_token(payload)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass it to your frontend client (or views) and use it to communicate with firebase:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/");
ref.authWithCustomToken(AUTH_TOKEN, function(error, authData) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Login Failed!", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Login Succeeded!", authData);
  }
});
```

as per https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/custom.html#section-rest-token-helper-libraries

Therefore I'd say it needs to go into the controller in the first place.